# PHP "AND or &&" Operator Problem

Tags: php, operators

I have:

```
if($this->itemCount <= 11 ) {

$item['subtotal'] = 12.95 * $item['qty'];
$item['price'] = 12.95;
$this->update_item($item['id'], $item['qty'], $item['price']);
}
```

But I need an "and" operator in there to check whether or not its also equal to or greater than 2.

```
if($this->itemCount <= 11 && => 2 )
```

I don't know how to do this in PHP. :(

Comment: Wow, I got a negative two for a question. Did I ask it poorly? Yipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to write the full expression out:

```
if($this->itemCount <= 11 && $this->itemCount >= 2 )
```

Comment: Wowza! 4 answers a nano second after I hit the submit button. That's crazysauce. Love it, though. Thanks to all of you for responding :) I will wait the 8 minutes and come back and pick this answer. (Said I had to wait to answer it ?? )

Answer (score 5):

```
if($this->itemCount <= 11 && $this->itemCount >= 2) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Missed 6 seconds on entering captcha :-( +1 for quicker post ;-)

Comment: This one is more correct, as the other two are using the 'double arrow' instead of the greater than or equal to expression.

Comment: @zerkms: great ... now that you've fixed your typo, my comment itself is inaccurate! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if($this->itemCount <= 11 && $this->itemCount >= 2 )
```

Answer (score 2):

`if($this->itemCount <= 11 && $this->itemCount => 2 )`

Comment: LOL, guess we got the answer, there really were no answers when I started typing...